# Layout, topbar, and sidebar positions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the top bar to sit where it is, the sidebar to sit to the right then the blocks to fill in the left of the sidebar where it can then continue to right side when the sidebar isn't there anymore (hence blocks).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQQ6s/24/)

Desired look:
[image: Desired look]

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#contents-h {
width: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    height: 100%;
}

.advertstop{
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}

.advertside{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 160px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.archiveentry{
    width: 168px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="contents-h">
    <div class="advertstop">dsf</div>
    <div class="advertside"></div>
    <div class="archiveentry"></div>
    <div class="archiveentry"></div>
    <div class="archiveentry"></div>
    <div class="archiveentry"></div>
    <div class="archiveentry"></div>
    <div class="archiveentry"></div>
    <div class="archiveentry"></div>
    <div class="archiveentry"></div>
<div class="archiveentry"></div>
```

Comment: did you tried setting, ```float:right;``` on ```.advertside```? seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/ZQQ6s/26/

Comment: no way so simple :P post it as an answer and i will accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
.advertside{ float:right; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/ZQQ6s/26/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Would there be an option to split up your content a little bit?

You could float: right on the advert.  But you'd have a lot more freedom if you split things up.  It'd also look a lot tidier.

Here's an example: **http://jsfiddle.net/Z75Nq/**

```
<div id="container">

<div id="top"></div>

<div id="left">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div id="right"></div>

<div id="bottom">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

</div>

#container {width: 510px;}
#container div {float: left; display: block;}
#top {width: 510px; height: 70px; background: red;}

#left {width: 306px; height: 150px;}
.box {width: 100px; height: 70px; margin: 2px 2px 0 0; background: green; }

#right {width: 204px; height: 214px; margin-top: 2px; background: black;}

#bottom {width: 510px;}
```